# How to make this CSS layout

Tags: css

[image]

Hi, i want to make this layout.

I am trying to do it in this way:

```
<div class="container" >
    <div class="picture_cont">...</div>
    <div class="info">...</div>
    <div class="price">...</div>
</div>
```

And CSS

```
.container {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    min-height: 160px;
}

.container .picture_cont {
    float: left;
    border-right: dotted 1px #777777;
    min-height: 160px;
    width: 100px;
}

.container .price {
    min-height: 160px;
    min-width: 160px;
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    border-left: dotted 1px #777777;
}

.container .info {
    float: left;
}
```

But i am getting this picture:
[image]
There is some issue with right column.

How to make it right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try rearranging your markup to have both columns occur before the larger content area, remove the float on the larger area, and apply `overflow:auto` to it.  This forces a new  [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting) restoring the flow of the `.info` container to be independent of the floated sidebars. (Note that you need to be careful of collapsing margins and non-staticly positioned elements to avoid scrollbars).

#### HTML

```
<div class="container" >
    <div class="picture_cont">...</div>
    <div class="price">...</div>
    <div class="info">text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
...

.container .info {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

#### Fiddle Demo

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/StMLm/
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/StMLm/show

Answer (score 3):

A mix of relative and absolute positioning will also do the trick. Something like this:

```
.container{position:relative;}
.picture_cont{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;bottom:0;width:100px;border-right:...}
.info{position:absolute;left:101px;top:0;bottom:0;right:151px;}
.price{position:absolute;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;left:150px;border-left:...}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C25xV/) to demonstrate.

Comment: I like this one better.  If the content is ever large enough to increase the height of the container, this method will allow for the borders to continue all the way down rather than stopping at their min-height. Edit: I would make one addition, however.  I would use left and right padding instead of `left` and `right` for the `.info` container (leaving it `position:static` instead of `absolute`) so that it can be larger than the min-height.

Comment: Edit 2 (locked myself out of editing my comment :P): `margin`... I meant `margin`.  It doesn't cary the background and still allows for internal padding with only one element.

Answer (score 2):

you are missing overflow:auto;

```
.container {
    border: solid 1px #000;
    min-height: 160px;
}

.container .picture_cont {
    float: left;
    border-right: dotted 1px #777777;
    min-height: 160px;
    width: 100px;
}

.container .price {
    min-height: 160px;
    min-width: 160px;
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    border-left: dotted 1px #777777;
    overflow:auto;
}

.container .info {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the items are floated and the middle has no specified width, the last item will "feel" the text of the second ("info") and be bumped down below it -- there is nothing telling `info` that, instead, it should stop 200px from the right edge. (150px? -- your picture and CSS don't match up)

One way to achieve that is to put right-padding of 200px (150px?) on `info` and then move the right-column into place with some CSS trickery: see [In Search of the Holy Grail](http://alistapart.com/article/holygrail)  for this classic solution.

A newer approach is to use `display:table` on the container `display:table-cell` on the 3 inner parts, set the width's on the left- and right-columns, and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You're using floats, so all your containers are independant, which means you can't base position and size on other containers. So in your case you'll have to specify a  width for your containers so that they are fixed and don't overlap each other.

Also try and put a "top" of 0px on your price container. This should help out.

Answer (score 0):

I typically use "inline-blocks" and fluid widths. This nice thing about this method is you can add a "min-width: 240px" and your UI will stack on mobile devices. ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cs3gA/1/))

```
div.container {
    width: 100%;
}

div.container div {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 10em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: -3px;
    padding:0;
}

div.info {
    width: 70%;
}

div.picture_cont,
div.price {
    width: 15%;
}
```